# Eclipse and database giving different results

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I have a large Java EE system connecting to an Oracle database via JDBC on Windows.

I am debugging a piece of code that does a retrieval of a field from the database.

The code is retrieving the field but when I run the exact same SELECT, copied from Eclipse, it does not yield any results.

Can any of you tell me why this would be the case?

I'm at a loss..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason is that the application might see uncommited data which it just created, but not yet committed.

When you execute the same statement in a different session it doesn't see the data (depending on your [transaction isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29))

Comment: That seems to be the case.When the transaction completes, I can then see the record in the database. Thanks

Comment: If the answer solved the problem it is practice at stackoverflow to accept it (click the check mark next to the votes for the answer)